# Trying to get property of non-object error when accessing to a appended attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose there is a `Website` model and I want to add an accessor named `min_withdraw` like this :

```
class Website extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'website_id';
    protected $appends = ['min_withdraw'];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'min_withdraw'
    ];

    function getMinWithdrawAttribute ()
    {
        if (!empty($this->settingOf('website','min_withdraw_user'))) {
            return $this->settingOf('website','min_withdraw_user');
        }
        return 100;
    }
 }
```

That accessor uses a `settingOf()` method to get a setting named `min_withdraw_user`. body of `settingOf()` is like:

```
    public function settingOf ($type, string $key, string $nestedKey = null)
    {
        $type = is_null($type) ? 'website' : $type;

        $setting = Setting::of($type, $key, $nestedKey, $this);

        return !empty($setting) ? $setting : Setting::of($type, $key, $nestedKey);
    }
```

Also `settingOf` uses a `Setting` model that holds some settings of different models defined in project.

All things like Output of `settingOf` method is right as I expected.

But when I want to access to that accessor `min_withdraw` alway I got this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\loverspay\resources\views\main\pages\index.blade.php)
```

Even whenever I used `{{dd($website->min_withdraw)}}` in blade template it return right value but when I want to echo that in normal way like `{{$website->min_withdraw}}` I got that error.

What is Problem?

**Update:**

In addition, I used bellow codes to get some websites and then sent them to desired blade template in a Controller :

```
        $websites =
            Website
                withCount('members')
                ->get()
                ->makeVisible(['min_withdraw']);

        return view('main/pages/index', compact('websites'));
```

Comment: Looking at your accessor: have you tried `$website->minWithdraw`?

Comment: @chilly, I updated my question. no I used `$website->min_withdraw`

Comment: Hard to follow without seeing the `Setting::of()` function, but is it relevant that your function `getMinWithdrawAttribute` references the array key `min_withdraw_user` while you seem to be looking for `min_withdraw`?

Comment: output of `Setting::of()` is always a single value. as I said even I use `dd($this->settingOf('website','min_withdraw_user')))` directly in accessor it return right value.